# android studio 0.81 cannot resolve symbol @string/hello

Tags: android, android-studio, migration

I wrote a small app that worked perfectly with AS 0.6. I upgraded then to 0.81 and now I'm getting errors because of unresolved symbols in my layouts at lines like these

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin
```

or this

```
android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

The exact error message is, e.g.

Cannot resolve symbol '@string/hello_world'

Those lines were inserted by AS 0.6 automatically when it created the activities and automatically defined in res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Points-ListView</string>
    <string name="button">Enter ListView</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Points</string>
    <string name="title_activity_point_list_view">PointListView</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_point_view">PointView</string>

</resources>
```

Does anybody know what this is due to and how to fix it? Again, no problems at all with this app when using AS 0.6. Thanks

Edit: I updated to 0.82 and I could open another 0.6 project w/o problems, I also was able to fix the problem in 0.81 with the 0.6 project I was speaking about here by replacing the
files

```
./build/intermediates/model_data.bin
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle.properties
gradlew
local.properties
settings.gradle
gradlew.bat
```

in the 0.6 project directory with the corresponding ones created by 0.81 for a simple "hello world" app. No clue why this worked

Comment: is it hello or hello_world?

Comment: did you tried a clean project?

Comment: @blackbelt: Sorry, it's hello_world. I tried to rename it but no success

Comment: @mapo: I cleaned the project, closed and reopened it. The problem remains

Comment: Basically, everything I defined in res/values is not recognized

Comment: can you try this: delete the string, build the project and then insert the string again and try it again ... ok nvm

Comment: @mapo: This is more than strange. I deleted the string and the build was, of course, not successful. Then I re-inserted the line and the build finished with 0 warns, 0 errs, Despite of this, the resources are still marked red in the IDE and I'm still seeing Cannot resolve symbol '@string/hello_world'

Comment: Ok that's weird, so it compiles correctly but shows the error? Then i would guess it is a bug by the new AS version?!

Comment: I just created a new "hello world" activity and the problem doesn't show up. Unfortunately, I don't see any obvious difference between my project and the new one :( I'd really be grateful if someone could help or I'll have to re-write quite a bit of code. In fact all of the projects I coded with 0.6 show the same behavior. Running AS on OpenSuSE Linux 13.1